# SQL Server stored procedure returning too many rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Working on a SQL Server stored procedure the logic works as desired. But for some reason its returning 50 odd select statement results when running the procedure (see attached screenshot)

I could have sworn I previously implemented a solution in a similar manner but clearly not.

When running through the procedure steps manually (i.e. not executing the procedure instead manually entering the params and then running the script) it works fine returning the single record I require.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Getdetails] 
    @Venue nvarchar(30), 
    @TeamA nvarchar(30), 
    @TeamB nvarchar(30)
AS 
    SELECT 
        *, hht + AHT AS HT, HFT + AFT AS FT 
    INTO
        #temptable2
    FROM
        rugby

    SELECT 
        *, FT-HT AS HT2 
    INTO
        #temptable
    FROM
        #temptable2

    ----deal with match specific
    SELECT 
        Venue, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, 
        AVG(HT) AS SPHT, AVG(FT) AS SPFT, 
        AVG(ht2) AS SP2HT, AVG(HT) AS GHT,
        AVG(FT) AS GFT, AVG(ht2) AS G2ht,
        AVG(HT) AS AHT, AVG(FT) AS AFT,
        AVG(HT) AS BHT, AVG(FT) AS BFT, AVG(FT) AS AVGFT12  
    INTO 
        #tempSP
    FROM 
        #tempTable
    WHERE 
        #temptable.Venue LIKE @Venue 
        AND #temptable.HomeTeam LIKE @TeamA 
        AND #temptable.AwayTeam LIKE @TeamB
    GROUP BY
        #temptable.Venue, #temptable.HomeTeam, #temptable.AwayTeam

    SELECT * FROM #tempSP

    EXEC [dbo].[Getdetails] @Venue = ' Treviso', @TeamA = 'Glasgow ', @TeamB = 'Edinburgh '
```

[image: procedure results]

Comment: Is that T-SQL / SQL Server? If so, what version of SQL Server? You should add more specific tags than simply `SQL`

Comment: Sounds like the calling method is passing the wrong data

Comment: SQL Server 2016 (Express)

Comment: What is in your messages tab when you run the query? It looks like you've got warnings there. Stylistically though you don't need all those temp tables, and you should `hometeam = @TeamA` instead of `hometeam like @teamA`. The like won't work the way you think it should

Comment: Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Getdetails, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 36]
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: doesn't really help :(

Comment: fyi changed the where clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I think I see the problem.

You are calling your proc within you proc. Try going into programmibilty/Stored Procedures, right click and edit the proc, remove the exec get_details line at the bottom and apply.

Comment: god that was annoying thank you so much for the quick responses guys! will defiantly try to contribute to the community in the future !

Answer (score 1):

If the code you've provided is the whole stored procedure then it isn't cleaning up after itself and you're loading the temp tables with lots of duplicate data.  Each run of the stored procedure will add another set to your results.

Comment: Yes thats the whole stored procedure, just implemented select distinct on each statement but no change...any code snippets to illustrate the "clean up"